# Ignore missing column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ibatis

How can I ignore missing columns on iBatis resultMap?

If I have this mapper

```
<resultMap id="DBEntity" class="CS_Entity">
    <result property="Id" column="Id" />
    <result property="Field1" column="f1" />
    <result property="Field2" column="f2" />
</resultMap>
```

for some queries I want to return the column f2, but how can I declare without adding for all the other queries the field f2 with the default value.

There is a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two resultsMap one with `f2`

```
<resultMap id="DBEntityWithF2" class="CS_Entity">
    <result property="Id" column="Id" />
    <result property="Field1" column="f1" />
    <result property="Field2" column="f2" />
</resultMap>
```

and another without `f2`

```
<resultMap id="DBEntity" class="CS_Entity">
    <result property="Id" column="Id" />
    <result property="Field1" column="f1" />
</resultMap>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `"select f2 as Field2 from yourTable"` in your sql, and use `resultClass="CS_Entity"` instead of using `resultMap` in your configuration. In this way, you needn't declare the mapping as above.